# xamarin: замена звука исходящего звонка

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, mono

Можно ли как-то с помощью Xamarin под Android перехватить(заменить) звук(гудок) исходящего звонка и выводить его вместо гудка?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду те длинные гудки, которые слышит вызывающий абонент?

Comment: @KoVadim именно их и имею ввиду.

Comment: Эти звуки проигрываются оборудованием оператора. Отсюда вывод - договаривайтесь с оператором, что бы он Вам предоставил апи. И, если оператор захочет, то он сделает его под xamarin для андроида. Но как по мне - то ни один оператор в здравом уме этого не сделает.

Вполне возможно, что на некоторых моделях телефонов можно будет это провернуть, но Xamarin для этого не нужен.

Comment: @KoVadim а как просто проигрывать поверх гудка свою мелодию во время звонка? Мне нужно написать приложение которое во время звонка проигрывает мелодию свою вместо гудков.

Comment: более чем уверен, что это сильно зависит от конкретной версии радиомодуля. И для некоторых устройств есть обходные пути.

Представьте, что это возможно официально. Это дает широчайшие возможности для вирусописателей и пранкеров.